# PHPStorm/Webstorm How to have file watcher remove .css if .scss is removed

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

I am using phpstorm 8.0.3 and I've been using the file watcher feature to compile SCSS to css files. However, when I delete a scss file, the *one* of the css file is left dangling. In netbeans, it somehow took care of it and deleted the file if the parent file was removed.

Just for testing I set up 2 file watchers. One compiles in place, one is the real file watcher that maps public/scss to public/css

### real file watcher

[image]

### directory structure

[image: enter image phere]

### dialogue & resulting dangling file

[image]
[image]

Comment: Q: Is your .css file located next to .scss and under custom node (collapsed) in a Project View panel (screenshot is welcome)?

Comment: It wasn't but I just added a file watcher to "compile in place" and the one that is underneath will get deleted, but I really want the file that is in a separate directory to get deleted.